# drawing a path between two marker on ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

Hey im new on ionic i wanted to draw a path between two markers (two points) using the google maps api but im blocked with that piece of code
Well by seeing a lot of tutorial i can't find any documentation about the route drawing by ionic their github repository never mentionned the route drawing i think it's not supported .

```
  loadMap() {

let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
  camera: {
    target: {
      lat: this.agence.latitude,
        //43.0741904,
      lng: this.agence.longitude,
        //-89.3809802
    },
    zoom: 14,
    tilt: 30
  }
};

this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map', mapOptions);

let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
  title: 'Radeema'+this.agence.nom,
  icon: 'red',
  animation: 'DROP',
  position: {
    lat: this.agence.latitude,
    lng: this.agence.longitude
  }
});
let positionMarker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
  title: 'votre position',
  icon: 'blue',
  animation: 'DROP',
  position: {
    lat: this.latitude,
    lng: this.longitude,

  }
});
this.map.addMarker({
  title: 'votre position',
  icon: 'green',
  animation: 'DROP',
  position: {
    lat: this.latitude,
    lng: this.longitude,
  }
})

let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;




directionsService.route({
  origin:{"lat": this.latitude, "lng": this.longitude} ,
  destination:      {"lat": this.agence.latitude, "lng": this.agence.longitude},

  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode['DRIVING']
}, (res, status) => {

  if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(res);
  } else {
    console.warn(status);
  }

});
this.map.addPolyline({
  points:  [
 {"lat": this.latitude, "lng": this.longitude},
 {"lat": this.agence.latitude, "lng": this.agence.longitude},

],
  'color' : '#fff51e',
  'width': 10,
  'geodesic': true
});  }
```

[image]

what should i do in this case i can't understand the source of the error

Comment: Can you show the `<script>` tag you use to load google maps api in your `index.html`?

Comment: <ion-header>


  <ion-navbar color="bluestrong">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>détails sur l'agence </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBfHFhBbVgNB3OzhTmiV1PEuJUju6b1bek"> </script>

</ion-header>



<ion-content padding  >
 <div align="center">Agence : {{agence.nom}}</div>
  <div  id="map"></div>

  Adresse de l'agence :  {{agence.adresse}}
</ion-content>

Comment: Ok you should see [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Comment: thanks for this example but it's written in js how can i integrate in my app then

Comment: Will post the code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple), converted from js to ts:

```js
private directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
private directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

initMap() {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }
    });
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


onChangeHandler() { // use this function in your dom or in your code when you want to dislpay the route
    calculateAndDisplayRoute();
};

calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
    this.directionsService.route({
        origin: userLocation,
        destination: agenceLocation,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

However I recommand [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/) plugin which let the user chose his favorite navigation application.

Comment: that's the same code that i useed they tell me that   they Cannot find name 'google'.

Comment: You need to do this command `npm install --save @types/googlemaps` and add this line in your component : `import { } from '@types/googlemaps';`